# Disable a model validation on an action method in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I want to disable a model validation on a specific Action method in a Controller. I have this scenario :

```
public class SomeDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SomeDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeDto>, ISomeDtoValidator
{
    public SomeDtoValidator ()
    {
        RuleFor(someDto=> someDto.Name).NotNull().WithMessage("Name property can't be null.");
    }
}
```

I have ISomeDtoValidator because I register all my validators in my own way :

```
public class Startup
{
    // .... constructor ....

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddMvc(setup => {
        //...others setups...
        }).AddFluentValidation();

        services.RegisterTypes(Configuration)
                .RegisterFluentValidation()
                .RegisterMappingsWithAutomapper()
                .RegisterMvcConfigurations();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I have this Action Method inside a Controller :

```
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSome(Guid someId, SomeDto someDto)
{
    //..... Manually binding someDto...

    var validator = new SomeValidator();
    validator.Validate(someDto);

    // Doing something more ........

    return Ok();
}
```

I disabled the modelBinding's MVC because I want to do something before binding SomeDto and, therefore, I don't want to apply any validator on SomeDto either. So, there is any way to achieve that ?? For example, something like this :

```
[DisableValidator] // Or [DisableValidator(typeof(SomeDtoValidator))] whatever
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSome(Guid someId, SomeDto someDto)
{
    //..... Manually binding someDto...

    var validator = new SomeValidator();
    validator.Validate(someDto);

    // Doing something more ........

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached my goal with @Alexey.Petriashev's help,  putting only a RuleSet in the validator. When pipeline calls the validator, it doesn't make a validation because the pipeline calls are without RuleSet. Bellow is an example of how I solved the issue:

```
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleSet("Manually", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Surname).NotNull();
            RuleFor(x => x.Forename).NotNull();
        });
    }
}

public ActionResult ActionWithoutValidationExecuted(Customer customer) 
{
    //..... Manually binding customer...

    var validator = new CustomerValidator();
    var validResult = validator.Validate(customer, ruleSet: "Manually");

    // Doing something more ........

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can skip validation by adding the following attribute to your action methods parameter:

```
public ActionResult Save([CustomizeValidator(Skip = true)] Customer model) {
  // ...
}
```

This is described in the docs here:
https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#validator-customization

Comment: Is there a similar attribute for the built-in asp.net validators?

Answer (score 3):

You can use RuleSets.

see: https://fluentvalidation.net/start#rulesets

usage: https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet#validator-customization

```
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Forename).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a first name");
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Address).Length(20, 250);

        RuleSet("Names", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Surname).NotNull();
            RuleFor(x => x.Forename).NotNull();
        });

        RuleSet("Empty", () =>
        {
        });
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        var validator = new CustomerValidator();
        var validationResult = validator.Validate(customer, ruleSet: "Names");
        // 2 errors: Surname and Forname
        validationResult = validator.Validate(customer, ruleSet: "Empty");
        // no errors
```

You can configure RuleSet in controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveNoValidate([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet="Empty")] Customer customer) {
// ...
}

public ActionResult SaveValidateNames([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet="Names")] Customer customer ) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: When I tried to put configured validator in the controller I got an error like "CustomerValidator is not an attribute class".

Comment: This code is 100% worked. I can push an example on github,
Thanks for copy-paste my answer! good job!

Comment: The method signature that you put does not work if "CustomizeValidator" is not an attribute. In the example that you put "CustomizeValidator" is not an attribute and therefore that example does not compile because it is a Validator. The inheritance Multiple in C # is not valid and would be the only way to be able to operate your code. I don't want the credit. I edited my answer and mentioned you, I apologize for not mentioning you the first time, my idea has put an answer to help someone else that had the same problem.

Comment: CustomizeValidator is included in FluentValidation