# ASP.NET Core disable validation when button is pressed

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, razor-pages

On the razor page, I have two buttons of type 'submit'.

The first button is used to add data to a local table, and the second button is used to add all columns in the database.

I want to prevent the first button from checking the validation of fields, only the second button checks the fields.

How to prevent the first button from checking the validation of the fields?

(ASP.NET Core)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `formnovalidate` to the first button input. And `formnovalidate`  attribute could skip the validation in client side,but could not skip validation in server side. So you could clear model state to skip validation in server side.
Below is a mvc demo, you can refer to it.

Custom.cs:

```
public class Custom
    {
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }        
    }
```

In HomeController.cs:

```
 public IActionResult Submit()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Submit(Custom custom)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();//clear model state to skip validation in server side
                return View("Submit");
            }
            return View("Submit");
        }
```

View:

```
@model nnnn.Models.Custom

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Submit";
}

<h1>Submit</h1>

<h4>Custom</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Submit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" formnovalidate class="btn btn-primary" />
                <input  type="submit" value="Save"  class="btn btn-secondary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are many ways to handle this...

You can direct to different controllers with different buttons and one of them would be like in this link and there are differents ways in it that you can use.. Check this out. I hope this helps.

[Disable Validation Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805484/disable-a-model-validation-on-an-action-method-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score -1):

You can create those two buttons like below.

The post request will be sent when the `type="submit"` button is triggered. In the other case, the get request can be executed and you can write your code inside the get related action method.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Category">Submit</button>
<a class="btn btn-success" asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Index" >Back</a>
```